# Mass delete ununused flow versions in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Is there a way to mass delete the unused versions of flows? 
I need to convert one text field to picklist which is referred to multiple flows and each flow has multiple versions. Is there any way to mass delete the unused ones?
any help is appreciated!

Comment: While I try to convert the field type all the inactive versions are popping up so in order to proceed I need to remove the reference.

Comment: Refer to answer posted in Salesforce StackExchange site [Mass Delete flow and flow versions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/355544)